# Set default value in case of error in update SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

Is there a way in Sql Server 2012 to set a default value on a column, for example:

```
convert(datetime,'1900/1/01', 120)
```

In case the update statement fails:

```
update Table1 set [UpdDate] = CONVERT(datetime, [UpdDate0])
```

For example the update statement encounters strange values (English or Chinese letters) on UpdDate0, so it cannot convert them to datetime and fails.

In those cases, I want to be able to set the default value I mentioned, or even a blank value, anything at all would be better than an error.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: you can use try_convert. Something like given below

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(float, 'test') IS NULL 
    THEN 'Cast failed'
    ELSE 'Cast succeeded'
END AS Result;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use try_convert. Something like given below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(float, 'test') IS NULL THEN 'Cast failed' ELSE 'Cast succeeded' END AS Result;
```

Comment: Prashant, after a conversion fails on a certain row, does your code convert all subsequent (following) records to 'Cast fail' ?

Comment: you mean if you are trying to convert a parameter and using that parameter to update all  the column , then yes it will